# Missing out a number on a for loop? (Java)

Tags: java

Right, before I start: this is a hw question.

We have to print out: -20, -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20

```
for(i = -20; i<25; i += 5)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

I've gotten it to output all the numbers, however, we're not allowed to output 0.

This question has me stumped . Any help please?

Comment: It's almost as if you need to do something different **IF** `i` is 0. Hm.

Comment: I don't care about what are you trying to sole please make your question self contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in programming there are conditional statements. In java the keyword for this is `if`. These statements only execute if the condition they check is true.

In your case you have a condition, "I want to print out all numbers EXCEPT for zero". You can take this and turn it into an if-statement. To do that you convert your statment to something like "as long as the number is not zero, print it out". So once you've reached this you can write:

`if (i != 0) System.out.println(i);`

So everytime you go through the loop the condition will check if `i` is any number different from zero. If it is the print statement will execute. When it is zero it will do nothing as the statment we placed does not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = -20; i<25; i += 5)
    {
     if(i != 0)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```